# App is accessing iPad microphone

Tags: ios, audio, simulator, csound

I'm currently working on an app that uses the Mobile Csound API to create a synthesizer. For some reason, the app accesses the iPad's microphone when running on the device, but not when running on the simulator. Does anyone know why that might be occurring?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the simulator doesn't have access to these sorts of hardware-level things.  I've never had success in capturing either audio from a mic or video from a camera.  In the case of video, the 'device' claims not to have a camera.

Edit: [this very old link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2104726?start=0&tstart=0) suggests that it may be possible for audio, so my answer may be wrong...

Comment: This is not my experience.  The development host's microphone is routed to the RemoteIO audiounit in the simulator.